# Limits Involving $e$ - Is this acceptable?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I'm currently studying a course in real analysis and have come across the following well known limit: $$\lim _{n\to\infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n=e$$

My question is: If you were given a question that asked you to compute $\lim _{n\to\infty}e^{1/n}$, would it be acceptable to do the following? $$\lim _{n\to\infty}e^{1/n}=\lim _{n\to\infty}\Bigg(\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n\Bigg)^{1/n}=1$$

I know you could just take the limit of the power of $e$ in this case, but I'm just thinking for harder questions that I have found.

Comment: I can't think of a similar counter-example off the top of my head, but no, this is not valid (even if the conclusion is true).

Comment: You cannot substitute $e$ and its limit definition.

Comment: Alright, thanks guys, that's what I wanted to know. I thought that would be the case, but I could find a few questions where this substitution resulted in the correct answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  You are trying to sneakily replace a nested limit with a diagonal limit.

You have $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n = \mathrm{e}$, so anywhere you have "$\mathrm{e}$", you can replace it with "$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n$" (possibly changing the limit variable to avoid using an already bound variable).

In $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathrm{e}^{1/n}$, $n$ is already bound, so we have to use a different placeholder variable in our substitution.  Let's use $m$.  We get
$$  \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{m} \right)^m \right)^{1/n}  $$
where I have wrapped our substitution in parentheses to avoid any possible ambiguity in meaning from the 2-dimensional notation.

Notice the process that this describes:

- For each member in a sequence of $n$s which goes to infinity, calculate the $1/n^{\text{th}}$ power of

  - For each member in a sequence of $m$s (which may be a different sequence for each of the values of $n$ we use) which goes to infinity,

    - Evaluate $\left( 1 + \frac{1}{m} \right)^m$
  - Finding its limit as $m \rightarrow \infty$.
- Finding its limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

This is not the same process as the single limit you write.  *In general*, the two variable limit can exhibit a range of behaviours that the diagonal limit (the limit along the diagonal line $m = n$) does not.

Comment: Nicely explained, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that the "more general" question you are asking is:

> If $a_n, b_n$ are sequences, and $$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = L$$ is it
>   true that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} L^{b_n} = \lim_{n \to \infty}
>  a_n^{b_n}.$$

I think this is a good question! I remember early in my career having similar thoughts, and not knowing how to decide if I could or not. But, this questions is still a math question so we should do what we always do, either prove that you can or exhibit a counter example which proves you cannot. So here we go.

In general, no you cannot. There might be special times where you can, but it would require justification.

As a counter example take $a_n = n^{1/n}$. Then (it is known and easy to prove) $$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 1.$$ Let $b_n = n.$ Then we have $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left[\lim_{j \to \infty} a_j \right]^{b_n} \lim_{n \to \infty} 1^{b_n}=\lim_{n \to \infty} 1^n = 1,$$ but $$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n^{b_n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} (n^{1/n})^n = \lim_{n \to \infty} n = \infty.$$

In your original example however, you could (without proof) write it as $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left[ \lim_{j \to \infty}(1+\frac{1}{j})^j \right]^{(\frac{1}{n})},$$ but in most cases, writing it in that way will not benefit the situation. But, it is correct.

Comment: I was initially thinking that it would work because you could use the algebra of limits somehow and take the limit of the $(1+1/n)^{n}$ part first and then take the limit of the power. But from Eric and your explanations, I can see how I was thinking incorrectly.

Comment: As long as you can justify that it is okay to write it that way (using limit laws or such) then it is fine, but without justification, as we have noted, it is not. It is good to question these things and find out though! You may notice in my example that I chose $b_n$ to be a divergent series, you can however get a counter example where both $a_n, b_n$ are convergent :)

Answer (score 2):

Consider the limit
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)=1\tag1
$$
and the limit
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\color{#C00}{1}^n=1\tag2
$$
If we were to substitute $(1)$ into the place of $\color{#C00}{1}$ in $(2)$ and slide the limit outside as is done in the question, we would get
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n=1\tag3
$$

Answer (score 0):

This type manipulation in general can be useful. In certain instances you can justify them by invoking continuity of some underlying function.

In this case one may consider the function $f(x)=x^y$ which is continuous on $(0,\infty)\times (-\infty,\infty)$.

Now, the different expressions you have are different paths of the limit of $f$ when $v\rightarrow (e,0)$, all of which must be equal to $f(e,0)$.

In general if $f(x,y)$ is continuous at $(x_0,y_0)$ then for all sequences $x_n\rightarrow x_0$ and $y_m\to y_0$ we have

$$\lim _{(x,y) \to (x_0,y_0)}f(x,y) = \lim_n \lim _m f(x_n,y_m) =  \lim_m \lim _n f(x_n,y_m) = f(x_0,y_0)$$